# adding a text field on press of a button on a view in iOS

Tags: ios, application-design

I have made a resume maker app in iOS. It only has two fields for the work experiences. However, a user can have more than one experience and the number is uncertain. So, my app is restricting a user to enter the information for only two work experiences. Now my boss wants me to add a button and when I tap it one more field should be displayed for the experience. So, this will allow a user to add as much experiences as he wants. I have searched a lot about it but couldn't find anything helpful. If you can kindly lead me to any resource or just give a demo.

Comment: Have a UITextfield in storyboard hide that one.while tapping the button make it visible.

Comment: How are you storing your data currently? Have you had any ideas yourself?

Comment: Will this give me a new text field each time I will press that button or it will work for one time?

Comment: u want programmatically?

Comment: @Wain, if you are asking about storing the data in Sqlite then, right now I am just using an object to store data being enter by the user which is later being passed to the database. But when I will be implementing this then I will add the experience entered in the new field in the same column and the new entries will be added as a string differentiating by ',' and will perform splitting later on.

Comment: @KathiravanG, yeah whatever the way it takes to perform the above mentioned task.

Comment: Have a UITextfield in storyboard in your view did load hide that one.  while tapping your button make it visible. It will work for u . the textfield appears whenever u tap the button . it's ok for u?

Comment: @KathiravanG The requirement is "as many as possible" though.

Comment: @KathiravanG, OK let me try, I will tell you what happens next. Thank You for your time. Though, it will keep me restricted to one field.

Comment: Use a table view and, if not core data, an array of objects.

Comment: One approach you can do is to have a `UITableView` and have each single experience populated in each cell. Then when an add button is pressed, a view like `UIPopover` can appear and let the user fill out the info. After the form is filled, one extra cell would be generated to display the new experience.

Comment: This approach works with deleting experience as well

Comment: You can also take data from alertview textfield and store that as you want and show it in tableview or whatever you want.

Comment: @veovo, post that as an answer let me accept it. Thanks man!!!

Comment: @Max, Perfect!! I have implemented the same thing(alert view containing textfield)for some other task in my app. Thanks man!!

Comment: No problem :). I just posted below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach you can do is to have a UITableView and have each single experience populated in each cell. Then when an add button is pressed, a view like UIPopover can appear and let the user fill out the info. After the form is filled, one extra cell would be generated to display the new experience. This approach works with deleting as well.